# NUnit: Generating dynamic test result output

Tags: c#, nunit

I have some N-unit test cases that have very convoluted tests. As a result, I'd like to include some steps in the test result XML. While I can partly achieve that with static strings, I do have occasions where I need the contents to be dynamic.

For instance, let's case I have a test case that takes in a folder and does something to the 3rd file, I'd like to be able to output something like

- Step 1: Reading folder "MyFolder"
- Step 2: Reading file "Myfile.txt"

. Where where MyFile.txt is a variable.

I have thought of using a Singleton output stream callable by each test case to output these things into a temporary file, but it is a bit inelegant.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Without sounding too sanctimonious it looks to me as though you are writing integration tests rather than Unit Tests. So, you might be better off writing a console application to run these tests for you. I'm taking a guess here but what you say does have the feel of using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the founder of the project, so this testing framework has already been put in place long before I started. As a result, even if the choice of test framework is wrong, I still need to get the job done. Obviously, I have a few ideas on some solutions, but I would like to find out about more elegant solutions that may be out there.

Comment: I can sympathise with that. How long do these tests take to run?

Comment: Not a long time for now. Maybe 15 minutes to run some 200+ cases

Comment: Is is possible to provide more information about what you are doing? Maybe show some code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no standard way of doing this. I achieved my objective by having the unit tests (which were intrinsically run as separate sub-processes) print to stdout and then manually parse that. Not very clean, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- use some of available .NET Logging Framework (NLog/log4net/etc.) or
- use [NUnit Custom Constraints](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Custom-Constraints) in which you can handle assert message in your own way.